# chrome overall font rendering issue 2016

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, rendering

I still got the problem of very bad font rendering in Google Chrome. I'm using version 50.0.2661.102 m. I deactivated "DirectWrite" and it got a bit better, but thin fonts are still horrible to read. I reinstalled chrome to get the default settings.

Here is a comparison with Firefox (top). Ignore the word spacings, its caused by responsive layout and justified text.

[firefox_comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmWPS.jpg)

This happens with all fonts on all pages. I saw a lot of workarounds, but they all assume to have Chrome 36 and below installed. Officially it is fixed since Chrome 37. But I get this on all of my PCs.

Is there a fix, or is chrome just bad with fonts?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem last night when I updated my Chromium-based Browser (Vivaldi). Text, especially certain colors or text against certain backgrounds, looked horrible. It looked jagged, unnatural or sometimes blurry. Luckily, I've rectified the issue:

- Type chrome://flags in the url bar and hit enter.
- Enable DirectWrite if you still have it disabled.
- Scroll down to **LCD text antialiasing** and select Enabled.
- Relaunch the browser.

Text should now appear crisp and smooth.

Comment: Last day or two I started seeing jaggy fonts, and this didn't fix it for me. Chrome  51.0.2704.84 m

Comment: They removed the DirectWrite flag from the latest version of Chrome. However enabling LCD text antialiasing correct my font rendering issues. You've certainly earned this upvote from me! Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, this didn't fix it for me - 53.0.2785.116 m (64-bit).

Comment: Didnt find DirectWrite in my version of Chrome, but enabling LCD text antialiasing fixed the "carved in stone" looking font problem for me.

Comment: Is there a programmatical fix for client side? I need this fixed not only on my computer but also my clients' computers as well.

Comment: I am on build 56 and i don't see the `DirectWrite` option at all, but i do have the `LCD text antialiasing` and that fixed my issue!

Comment: Interestingly enough it fixed my issue by Enabling LCD text antialiasing.  After that it didn't mater if I disable or enabled the flag.  Just changing it fixed the issue permanently.

Comment: I got it fixed by enabling the "Override software rendering list" setting aka "#ignore-gpu-blacklist".  I read about it here https://gettingthingstech.com/how-to-fix-jagged-font-rendering-in-google-chrome/  I feel like my eyes can breathe again.

Comment: for me "LCD text antialiasing" was already Enabled, after I've disabled this option font is much smoother.

Comment: DISABLING LCD Text Anti-aliasing did the trick for me.  Strange.  It was enabled and my fonts looked horribly jagged.  Some letters looked bold, others didn't, and no text had any kind of smoothing on it until I disabled anti-aliasing.

Comment: tried all your suggestions and combinations of them in vain. surprisingly, stackoverflow renders perfectly, but for example the chrome://flags page itself renders eyesore. my version is 67.0.3396.87 64 bit on Windows 8.1 Enterprise [de-AT]. Same problem on Windows 10N [en-US]. filed another problem report via their built-in form.

Answer (score 28):

If by chance you're using Chrome/Firefox on Windows 10, I found the fix!

Control panel > Fonts > Adjust Clear Type

Follow the instructions and bam! All fonts on all browsers are clear and no longer jagged or blurry. :-)

Comment: This did it for me: But I had to disable the LCD text antialisaing in chrome otherwise it actually looked worse.

Comment: Confirm - Windows 7 Pro 64 bit, Crome v54.0.2840.71 m (64-bit), disabling the `LCD text antialiasing' and doing Windows Clear Type Text adjustment and having font smoothing enabled

Comment: Confirm! Windows 10 x64. All other solutions wont work but your is working! (But i have to complete restart Chrome!)

Answer (score 5):

On Chrome 60.0.3112.113, in chrome://flags I set "Accelerated 2D canvas" to Disabled and this fixed the issue for me

I was accessing Chrome via RDC

Answer (score 2):

Resetting all chrome flags to default fixed this for me. I must have done something "iffy" in the past that I couldn't remember.

Answer (score 0):

with all prvious suggestion, in linux fedora, chrome 69, the issue is still there:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

In my case i have to disable `DirectWrite` in `chrome://flags`

Version: 51.0.2704.106 m

*Dont forget to restart the Chrome Browser.*

Answer (score -1):

Resetting the flags in 'chrome://flags/' worked for me as mentioned by Ianbeks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjUNO.png

Answer (score -1):

Please be aware that Chrome made some changes with the flags in the last version. The `DirectWrite` removed and now the flag you need to disable is `chrome://flags/#enable-font-cache-scaling`.

Answer (score -1):

I've installed this addon: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/change-font-family-style/aabledekpjmoghdjnpnhfkfpmjifklpb/related

and then:
Right click onto add-on icon and select "options" (screenshot is in Turkish)
[image]

Then, in the opened window, I wrote "auto" in the input area and saved.

[image]

It works!

Answer (score -2):

I tried all the fixes listed and then found that I fixed the problem by changing the "Zoom"(magnifying glass next the favourites star on the far right near menu) from 500% back to 100%

Comment: You were at 500% zoom and didn't notice..?